# Define a branch for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{z}}$ and show it is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Define a branch for $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{z}}$ and show it is analytic.

I defined a branch $(-\pi, \pi)$, and so that means the function $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{z}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{y=0,x\leq 0\right\}$.

I am trying to analyze when such a function is in the deleted area. Already from $\sqrt{z}$, $y$ must be zero. It remains to consider the case when $x\leq 0$. Since there's an added $+1$ inside the square root, does this change $x\leq 0$ to $x\leq -1$? And so the analytic domain is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{y=0,x\leq -1\right\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $1+\sqrt z= -t$ with $t \geq 0$ then $z=(1-t)^{2}$. The range of $(1-t)^{2}$ on $[0,\infty)$ is $[0,\infty)$ so $z \in [0,\infty)$ which is not true. Hence $1+\sqrt z$ does not lie on the negative real axis when $z$ does not lie on the negative real axis. Hence $\sqrt {1+\sqrt z }$ is well defined and analytic on the complex plane with $(-\infty, 0]$ removed.

Answer (score 0):

$ {w = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{z}},(  z  \;  \epsilon  \;  C) \mapsto  circle \; |w|\measuredangle\phi,\ by \ Moivre \ theorem \ to \ determine \ the\ complex\ roots \ it \ follows \ that: \ w^n \ = \ r^n \  ( cos(\ n \phi )\ + sin(\ n \phi) )
 \  let's  \; define  \; this \;  circle  \; as  \; f(z).} $ 
 $ { A \;positive \ branch \; is \; defined \;  in \ the \; domain  \;  0\le\phi< 2\pi \; , ( or \;  restricting  \; z,) \Rightarrow hence \;} z0 \ne \ z1  \; is \;  fulfilled   \; that\; f(z0) \; \ne \; f(z1), \;  hence  \; f(z)  \; is  \; analityc. $ }

Comment: Rectifiqué la respuesta despues de repasar el tema, no había entendido bien que se pedía. Sorry